# How to properly handle a prop change with a LitElement component?

Tags: polymer, web-component, lit-element

My scenario:
I have a web component created with LitElement which has an object property.
In order to initialise it, i am waiting for the element to get created:

```js
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        const instance = document.querySelector("#myInstance");
        instance.config = {
          data: [
            { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 32 },
            { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Boe", age: 30 },
          ]
        };
      });
    </script>
    <my-component id="myInstance"></my-component>
```

Let's say that i am going to change this `data` prop from time to time.
I would like to check the value of the `data` once it is changed and then decide what i should do next. In order to do that, this is the code of my web component:

```js
@customElement("my-component")
export class MyComponent extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Object }) data: Object;

  protected updated(_changedProperties: Map<PropertyKey, unknown>): void {
    console.log(_changedProperties);
  }

  render() {
      return html`
        <div>blabla</div>
      `;
  }
}
```

The problem is that `_changedProperties` map has `data` but it is still undefined.
What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changedProperties is a Map of all the property names that changed... e.g. you can use it to check what changed - if you want to access the actual value you can use the property directly.

it look like this

```
if (_changedProperties.has('myProperty')) {
  // react to a myProperty change
  console.log('The new value of myProperty is', this.myProperty);
}
```